# Jgrasp debugger not showing local variables

Tags: jgrasp

I started to realize that my debugger for `jGRASP` isn't showing local variables anymore.It only shows static variables. I'm not sure when it started but my version is `2.0.3_06`. I've tried the Eclipse debugger and it worked fine, so I know the problem is with `jGRASP`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is shown next "Locals"? Is it (not available: not compiled in debug mode)? If so, check on "Build" > "Debug Mode". Otherwise, use "Help" > "Report a Bug" to report this.